# get content of spans in a div and display it in a list

Tags: html, jquery, html-lists

I have some spans inside my content, and I'd like to get the content of each of them and display it in a list.

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks.

```js
let container = $("#article-content");
let spans = container.find(".footnote");

let outputP = $("#footnotes");

for (let span of spans) {
  let listElem = document.createElement("li");
  listElem.textContent = span.html;

  outputP.appendChild(listElem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  Post emensos insuperabilis expeditionis eventus <span class="footnote">footnote 1</span> asperitate nimia cuncta foedabat. propinquitate <span class="footnote">footnote 2</span> enim Excogitatum est super his<span class="footnote">footnote 3</span>  adsistendo pervadendoque divites domus egentium habitu quicquid noscere poterant vel audire latenter intromissi per posticas in regiam nuntiabant, id observantes conspiratione concordi, ut fingerent quaedam et cognita duplicarent in peius, laudes vero
  supprimerent Caesaris, quas invitis conpluribus formido malorum inpendentium exprimebat.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
$("#container span").each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $("<li>").text(text).appendTo("#footnotes");
});
```

This will find all `span` in the element with id `container`, then it will append a `li` element with the text of the span inside it.

**Demo**

```js
$("#container span").each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $("<li>").text(text).appendTo("#footnotes");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  Post emensos insuperabilis expeditionis eventus <span class="footnote">footnote 1</span> asperitate nimia cuncta foedabat. propinquitate <span class="footnote">footnote 2</span> enim Excogitatum est super his<span class="footnote">footnote 3</span>  adsistendo pervadendoque divites domus egentium habitu quicquid noscere poterant vel audire latenter intromissi per posticas in regiam nuntiabant, id observantes conspiratione concordi, ut fingerent quaedam et cognita duplicarent in peius, laudes vero
  supprimerent Caesaris, quas invitis conpluribus formido malorum inpendentium exprimebat.
</div>

<ul id="footnotes">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use either jQuery or raw JavaScript, but not both. It's confusing to have some native elements and some jQuery objects in a function, and sometimes it just doesn't work. You really don't need jQuery for something like this anyway. See https://youmightnotneedjquery.com.
2. The [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function returns only the *first* element that matches. Also, it's intended to accept a filter function, not a selector string. You want [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
3. There's no element with ID `footnotes` in your markup. You need to either include it or create it with JavaScript.

Bonus protip: If you use single quotes for JavaScript and double quotes for HTML (including HTML attributes *inside* JavaScript) you'll rarely have the need to escape quote characters. The nice thing is that most developers use double quotes for HTML, so you'll be consistent.

```js
const containerEl = document.getElementById('container');
const textEls = containerEl.querySelectorAll('.footnote');
const outputListEl = document.createElement('ul');

textEls.forEach(textEl => {
  const listItemEl = document.createElement('li');
  listItemEl.textContent = textEl.innerText;

  outputListEl.appendChild(listItemEl);
});

containerEl.appendChild(outputListEl);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  Post emensos insuperabilis expeditionis eventus <span class="footnote">footnote 1</span> asperitate nimia cuncta foedabat. propinquitate <span class="footnote">footnote 2</span> enim Excogitatum est super his<span class="footnote">footnote 3</span>  adsistendo pervadendoque divites domus egentium habitu quicquid noscere poterant vel audire latenter intromissi per posticas in regiam nuntiabant, id observantes conspiratione concordi, ut fingerent quaedam et cognita duplicarent in peius, laudes vero
  supprimerent Caesaris, quas invitis conpluribus formido malorum inpendentium exprimebat.
</div>
```